# Arraylist of edittext

Tags: android

hi i have an arrayList of different editTexts and i want the inputted values will get the sum of the five editTexts and display this to an arrayList of textView how will i do that? please help me..i have a hard time of thinking on it..thanks in advance..

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final TextView excellent_val = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.excellent_val);
TextView best_val = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.best_val);
TextView better_val = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.better_val);
TextView good_val = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.good_val);
TextView poor_val = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poor_val);

final EditText  respondents = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.respondents);
final EditText  questions = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.questions);
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);




button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub








        String c = questions.getText().toString();
        final Integer count = Integer.parseInt(c);

        questions.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        respondents.setText(respondents.getText().toString());

        final TableLayout table = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        table.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        table.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);




        final TableRow tableRow = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());               


        TextView txt = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
        TextView txt2 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
        TextView txt3 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
        TextView txt4 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
        TextView txt5 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
        TextView txt6 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());

        tableRow.addView(txt);
        tableRow.addView(txt2);
        tableRow.addView(txt3);
        tableRow.addView(txt4);
        tableRow.addView(txt5);
        tableRow.addView(txt6);



        tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        txt.setText("Question  ");
        txt2.setText("Excellent   ");
        txt3.setText("Best     ");
        txt4.setText("Better   ");
        txt5.setText("Good     ");
        txt6.setText("Poor     ");

        txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


        table.addView(tableRow);





        final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        int j=0;
        for(j = 1; j<=count; j++){

            Random rnd = new Random(); 
            int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)); 

             tableRow2  = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());
             excellent = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
             best = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
             better = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
             good = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
             poor = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
             mean_in = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

             name = new TextView (getApplicationContext());

            excellent.setBackgroundColor(color);
            best.setBackgroundColor(color);
            better.setBackgroundColor(color);
            good.setBackgroundColor(color);
            poor.setBackgroundColor(color);


            name.setText("Q#"+Integer.toString(j));
            mean_in.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            tableRow2.addView(name);
            tableRow2.addView(excellent);
            tableRow2.addView(best);
            tableRow2.addView(better);
            tableRow2.addView(good);
            tableRow2.addView(poor);
            tableRow2.addView(mean_in);
            table.addView(tableRow2);


            excellentList.add(excellent);
            bestList.add(best);
            betterList.add(better);
            goodList.add(good);
            poorList.add(poor);

            mean_array.add(excellent);
            mean_array.add(best);
            mean_array.add(better);
            mean_array.add(good);
            mean_array.add(poor);

            MEAN.add(mean_in);



        }


        //Make an ArrayList of EditText
        //Put all excellent EditTexts in it.
        //In the onClick go through this list and append all the getText().toString() of these EditTexts




        tableRow1 = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());

        final Button get = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        tableRow1.addView(get);
        get.setText("Get!");
        get.setTextSize(8);




         //******************************************************************************// 
        //                              GET!                                    //  
       //******************************************************************************//

        get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){




            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String population = respondents.getText().toString();
                double n = Double.parseDouble(population);

                double Population = 0;
                double final_Population =0;
                    Population = n/(1+(n*(0.003*0.003)));
                    final_Population = Math.ceil(Population);

                String val_excellent=null;
                double weigthed_ex=0;
                double result =0;
                double final_result=0;



                for(EditText excellent : excellentList){
                    val_excellent= excellent.getText().toString(); 
                    double values = Double.parseDouble(val_excellent);
                    for(int z=0;z<val_excellent.length();z++){
                        weigthed_ex =values*5/final_Population;
                    }
                    String weight_excellent =String.format("%.3g",weigthed_ex);
                    get.setEnabled(false);
                    excellent.setTextSize(11);
                    excellent.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    excellent.setEnabled(false);
                    excellent.setText((weight_excellent));
                  }


                String val_best=null;
                double weigthed_best=0;
                for(EditText best: bestList){
                    val_best = best.getText().toString();
                    double values_best = Double.parseDouble(val_best);
                    for(int y =0; y<val_best.length();y++){
                        weigthed_best = values_best*4/final_Population;
                    }
                String weight_best =String.format("%.3g",weigthed_best);    
                best.setTextSize(11);
                best.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                best.setEnabled(false);
                best.setText(weight_best);

                }



                String val_better=null;
                double weigthed_better=0;
                for(EditText better: betterList){
                    val_better = better.getText().toString();
                    double values_better = Double.parseDouble(val_best);
                    for(int k =0; k<val_better.length();k++){
                        weigthed_best = values_better*3/final_Population;
                    }
                String weight_better =String.format("%.3g",weigthed_better);    
                better.setTextSize(11);
                better.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                better.setEnabled(false);
                better.setText(weight_better);

                }


                String val_good=null;
                double weigthed_good=0;
                for(EditText good: goodList){
                    val_good = good.getText().toString();
                    double values_good = Double.parseDouble(val_good);
                    for(int l =0; l<val_good.length();l++){
                        weigthed_good = values_good*2/final_Population;
                    }
                String weight_good =String.format("%.3g",weigthed_good);    
                good.setTextSize(11);
                good.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                good.setEnabled(false);
                good.setText(weight_good);

                }

                String val_poor=null;
                double weigthed_poor=0;
                for(EditText poor: poorList){
                    val_poor = poor.getText().toString();
                    double values_poor = Double.parseDouble(val_poor);
                    for(int m =0; m<val_poor.length();m++){
                        weigthed_poor = values_poor*1/final_Population;
                    }
                String weight_poor =String.format("%.3g",weigthed_poor);    
                poor.setTextSize(11);
                poor.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                poor.setEnabled(false);
                poor.setText(weight_poor);
                }

                Button getMean = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                tableRow1.addView(getMean);

                getMean.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String a=null;
                        String b=null;
                        String c=null;
                        String d=null;
                        String e=null;

                        double f=0;
                        double g=0;
                        double h=0;
                        double i=0;
                        double j=0;

                        double mean=0;

                        for(TextView mean_in: MEAN){
                            for(EditText excellent :excellentList){
                                a = excellent.getText().toString();
                                f= Double.parseDouble(a);
                            }

                            for(EditText best :bestList){
                                b = best.getText().toString();
                                g= Double.parseDouble(b);
                            }
                            for(EditText better :betterList){
                                c = better.getText().toString();
                                h= Double.parseDouble(c);
                            }
                            for(EditText good :goodList){
                                d = good.getText().toString();
                                i= Double.parseDouble(d);
                            }
                            for(EditText poor :poorList){
                                e = poor.getText().toString();
                                j= Double.parseDouble(e);
                            }







                            mean = f+g+h+i+j/5;
                            mean_in.setText(" ");
                          }

                    }

                });



                        TextView mean = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        mean.setText("Mean");
                        mean.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        tableRow.addView(mean);

                }  


});
```

here is the output...

[image]

Comment: where is arraylist of TextView

Comment: @Shakeeb Ayaz sir i put mean_in in an arrayList of textView,

Comment: You didn't say what went wrong with your code. But I did notice this: `mean = f+g+h+i+j/5;`. You need parentheses around the sum before dividing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i cannot retrive the values of my five edittext

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for(j = 1; j<=count; j++)

use for(**j = 0**; j<=count; j++)